# Unable to install Ethernet Driver in 14.04LTS

Tags: ethernet

**strong text**Recently i  had installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit.

It is dual-boot with Windows 7 Ultimate. The Ethernet works good in Windows but in Ubuntu does not work.Actually,it worked for 2-3 days,then suddenly it stopped .. so, i tried to reinstall the driver(RTL8101E/RTL8102E), but every time it shows error asking about the "PRIVATE KEY"...

What is this private key? ...
wireless works very much fine....

plzz post ur suggestions regarding this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you add a custom repository you have to use the command `apt-key add [whatever-the-key-is]`. When you try to install something from the custom repository without the right apt key, you will get a key error like the one you are seeing. Go back and make sure you added the right key, and then `apt-get update && apt-get install --reinstall [RTL8101E/RTL8102E driver packagename]`